# SendKeys() NOT every time success to the input element through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Im using Selenium(v4.0.30319) with Chrome browser.
Already try a few setting to make sure the result always success.
Below is most success result. Any advice to make sure the success rate more. 99.99% :)

HTML :

```
<lw-text-input _nghost-qxr-c303="" class="ng-star-inserted lwCanvasWrapperComponent" tabindex="17" 
        style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 802.368, 241.776); visibility: visible; transform-origin: 0px 0px;">
        <textarea _ngcontent-qxr-c303="" name="PrimeInputTextArea" pinputtextarea="" lwngmodelcomponent="" tooltipposition="right" tooltipstyleclass="lwErrorTooltip" tooltipevent="focus" appendto="body" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" droppable="" rows="1" cols="6" class="ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" style="visibility: visible; width: 72px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        </textarea>
        </lw-text-input>

<lw-text-input _nghost-qtr-c303="" class="ng-star-inserted lwCanvasWrapperComponent" tabindex="6" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 781.776, 152.568); visibility: visible; transform-origin: 0px 0px;">
    <textarea _ngcontent-qtr-c303="" name="PrimeInputTextArea" pinputtextarea="" lwngmodelcomponent="" tooltipposition="right" tooltipstyleclass="lwErrorTooltip" tooltipevent="focus" appendto="body" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" droppable="" rows="1" cols="8" class="ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" style="visibility: visible; width: 169.92px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            </textarea>
            </lw-text-input>
```

C# :

```
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myField8 = wait2.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("lw-text-input[style='transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 802.368, 241.776); visibility: visible; transform-origin: 0px 0px;']")));

            if (myField8.Enabled)
            {
                SendKeysToElement(myField8, "AA25");
            }



 public void SendKeysToElement(IWebElement element, string text)
        {
            
            string bar = string.Empty;
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                bar += c;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);  // wait for 200ms between each character
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            element.Click();
            element.SendKeys(bar);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `CssSelector` a bit Flaky. Try with below selector and check if that improves code your reliability.

```
IWebElement myField8 = wait2.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("lw-text-input.lwCanvasWrapperComponent")));
```

or

```
IWebElement myField8 = wait2.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("lw-text-input.lwCanvasWrapperComponent > textarea[name='PrimeInputTextArea']")));
```

Comment: 1st option : Not valid, cause will go to other fields. The example HTML only for 1 field.  2nd option : return error 'Timed out after 10 seconds'.

Comment: In that case I need the check the source, Is it possible to share the url?

Comment: Already update new field, can compare each field. I think the matrix location only is unique key.

Answer (score 0):

For my case already change FindElement using "**By.XPath**".
Then it is more efficient and reliable. Thanks :)

```
IWebElement myField8 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/lw-root/lw-main/div/lw-application-info/lw-form-application-viewer/div/div/lw-transform-tool-canvas/div/div/div/lw-text-input[15]/textarea"));
```